# Heap corruption detected error in VS, but working fine with other IDE

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, heap-memory

I'm doing something with VoidPtr and when i tested out my codes on other IDE such as Quincy or Eclipse, I don't have any problem running them.

However, when i tried to run my codes in Visual Studio 2015, the display is fine, but i stumbled upon an error called

> HEAP CORRUPTED DETECTED: after Normal block #138 at (some address)

I can't locate where is the error because it is displaying the address of a pointer which is even harder for me to debug.

I'm trying to union the data of 2 void pointer array.

```
void unionAnimalArray(VoidPtr* animalArray, int size, VoidPtr* animalArray2, int size2)
{
    int sizeu;

    VoidPtr *vpArray = &animalArray[0];
    VoidPtr *vpArray2 = &animalArray2[0];
    VoidPtr *end = &animalArray2[size2];

    VoidPtr *su = new VoidPtr[12];
    su = animalArray;

    sizeu = size;

    VoidPtr tempu;

    bool check;

    while (vpArray2 != end)
    {
        do
        {
            tempu = *vpArray2;
            check = true;
            for (int j = 0; j<size; j++)
            {
                if (j == 0)
                    vpArray = &animalArray[0];
                if (*(static_cast<Animal*>(tempu)) == *(static_cast<Animal*>(*vpArray)))
                {
                    check = false;
                    break;
                }
                ++vpArray;
            }
            if (!check)
                ++vpArray2;
        } while (!check && vpArray2 != end);

        if (vpArray2 != end)
        {
            vpArray = &su[sizeu];
            *vpArray = tempu;
            ++sizeu;
            ++vpArray2;
        }
    }
    cout << "The union is" << endl;
    cout << "\t{";
    printAnimalArray(su, sizeu);

    delete[]su;

}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior most likely.

Answer (score 1):

```
void unionAnimalArray(VoidPtr* animalArray, int size, VoidPtr* animalArray2, int size2)
...
VoidPtr *su = new VoidPtr[12]; // su points to new memory
su = animalArray; // su now points to same memory as animalArray2
...
delete[]su; // deletes memory shared with animalArray2
```

An array should be copied element-wise instead of assignment:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size2; ++i) {
    su[i] = animalArray[i];
}
```

---

You can keep buffer `su` in automatic memory as you know the size of buffer in compile time:

```
VoidPtr su[12];
```

Comment: I believe, this is not the issue, because when i attempted to intersect my 2 voidpointer with the above method is fine, but when i attempted to union them, then the issue occurred. Nonetheless, I tried your method, but somehow the problem is still there.

Comment: ***I believe, this is not the issue*** This is certainly a bug. It may not be the only bug but the original code is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Think a little bit about this:

```
VoidPtr *su = new VoidPtr[12];
su = animalArray;
```

Where did the 12 new VoidPtr-s go?
Who and when they will be deleted ?

Comment: I've deleted them at the end of the function `delete[]su`

Comment: However you are not deleting the buffer you allocated with `new VoidPtr[12];` You are attempting to delete the buffer that `animalArray` points to instead and this probably is a double delete depending on how `animalArray` is allocated.

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan: no, you did not. after doing `su = animalArray`, su is anymore holding the new returned pointer.
You deleted another thing, that -in fact- you shouldn't.

An assignment between pointers does not do what you think it does.